# Can PKCS5Padding be in AES/GCM mode?

Tags: java, algorithm, aes, padding, aes-gcm

What's the padding mode for AES/GCM? I understood it can be NoPadding, as in ECB mode it can be PKCS5Padding, how about in GCM mode? in JCE interface, we need provide "algorithm/mode/padding" ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)).

So I used the following code to get the instance and it works in JDK but failed in IBM SDK which says

> cannot find provider for supporting AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding

```
 Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
```

What's real use case for padding?

Comment: Padding describes how blocks in the chain are aligned and filled up to match the expected block size. The JRE can run with different security provider. The Oracle SDK includes his own very low secure USA pleasant Oracle Security Provider. I dont know which Security Prodiver is default in IBM SDK. Best practice is to include your own security provider when working with different JREs Providers, like BouncyCastle.  Or use the Security provider of the target system on dev system, like when you develop for android where OpenSSl Security Provider is Default. Hope that helps

Comment: This is best Security Provider I know: https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need do not introduce 3rd libs. so I need use JDK build-in provider. like SUNJCE, but in IBM sdk, I guess it provide its own provider, but however, my question is, do "AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding" is legal value? I did not found any example use PKCS5Padding in GCM and even http://isaacyang1988.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Crypt/src/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AESTest.java this article have test case like that it is not right pattern

Comment: Look at answer from Artjom. Otherwise write a program that inspects the default security provider of your jre and print out possible values for your desired algorithm. Select values which exist on both side and you are fine

Answer (score 23):

GCM is a streaming mode which means that the ciphertext is only as long as the plaintext (not including authentication tag). GCM doesn't require a padding. This means that the PKCS5Padding version is actually only a synonym for NoPadding for convenience during programming.

Some providers don't have this strange mode. Java has pluggable cryptographic providers and basically all JRE distributions have a default cryptographic provider which may have different cipher strings and defaults than those of other providers.

There are cases where padding the plaintext makes sense. For example, you can hide the length of the actual plaintext by appending a random length PKCS5Padding.

Comment: Thanks, that says we need correct to Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding"); right?

Comment: Yes, `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");` is the proper way. It's probably the same thing as with `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` which is actually only `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");`.

Comment: I don't have the IBM provider, but you can check if both are interoperable. By (1) encrypting with padding and decrypting without padding and (2) encrypting without padding and decrypting with padding.

Comment: Hey @ArtjomB., you've helped me with my cryptography questions a lot.. I'm using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` algorithm for Password Hashing. It's working in live server. But I doesn't seem to work with Java 7 but only in Java 8. Is there any way that I can able to use this algorithm in Java 7?

Comment: @user1354678 I don't know for sure, but I think it worked for me in Java 7. You can try to add the BouncyCastle provider which probably provides this.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Any idea why *SonarQube* is giving me _Make sure that encrypting data is safe here._ for `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` and `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");`. Aren't they safe any more? In the documentation(https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4787) it says that _Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) with no padding should be preferred to the following combinations which are not secured_. But it still gives the error...

Comment: @DionisBeqiraj The RSA-case should be clear since no OAEP is used. GCM on its own is quite good, but has some failure modes, where the nonce must never repeat under the same key. It would be better to use a 2-pass mode like AES-SIV, but that is computationally expensive and the encryption/decryption cannot be streamed. I don't know for sure, but that is a hunch. It could also be a bug in the SonarQube rule set.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yeah, right, for `RSA` case I should implement OAEP, as suggested. But for AES is strange... ?

Comment: I have discovered that OpenJDK Java / JSSE versions up through 11 will accept `AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding` but Java 17 will not: you have to switch to `NoPadding`. Java 11 [doesn't require support for AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html) not I guess is still supports `PKCS5Padding` as a synonym for `NoPadding`. It appears that Java 17 removes this alias.