# Out of memory exception when decrypt large file using Cipher

Tags: java, exception, encryption, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I was trying to implement an encrypt/decrypt program using classes under javax.crypto and file streams for input/output.
To limit the memory usage, I run with **-Xmx256m** parameter.

It works fine with encryption and decryption with smaller files.
But when decrypt a huge file (1G in size), there is an out of memory exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decrypt(GaloisCounterMode.java:505)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.update(CipherCore.java:782)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.update(CipherCore.java:667)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineUpdate(AESCipher.java:380)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1831)
    at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:166)
```

Here is the decrypt code:

```
private final int _readSize = 0x10000;//64k

...

GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(gcmTagSize, iv);
Key keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, keyParts[0]);
Cipher decCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");

decCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);

try (InputStream fileInStream = Files.newInputStream(inputEncryptedFile);
    OutputStream fileOutStream = Files.newOutputStream(outputDecryptedFile)) {
    try (CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutStream, decCipher)) {
        long count = 0L;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_readSize];

        int n;
        for (; (n = fileInStream.read(buffer)) != -1; count += (long) n) {
            cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
}
```

The key parameters like gcmTagSize and iv are read from a key file, and it works fine with smaller files, like some one around size of 50M.

As I understand, every time there are only 64k data passed to decipher, why it runs out of heap memory?
How can I avoid this?

**Edit:**

Actually I have tried with 4k as buffer size, failed with same exception.

**Edit 2:**

With more testing, the max file size it can handle is around 1/4 of the heap size. Like, if you set **-Xmx256m**, files bigger than **64M** will fail to decrypt.

Comment: Reduce the read size to something saner like 16K or even 4K.

Comment: 4k failed with same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **bad news** are: IMHO the error is caused by an bad implementation of AES GCM-mode in native Java. Even if you could get it to work you will find that the decryption of a large file (1 GB or so) will take a lot of time (maybe hours ?). 
But there are **good news**: you could/should use BouncyCastle as service provider for your decryption task - that way the decryption will work and it's much faster.

The following full example will create a sample file of 1 gb size, encrypts it with BouncyCastle and later decrypts it. In the end there is a file compare to show that plain and decrypted file contents are equal and the files will be deleted. **You need temporary a total of more than 3 GB free space on your device to run this example.**

Using a buffer of 64 KB I'm running this example with this data:

Milliseconds for Encryption: 14295 | Decryption: 16249

A buffer of 1 KB is a little bit slower on encryption side but much slower on decryption task:

Milliseconds for Encryption: 15250 | Decryption: 21952

A last word regarding your cipher - "AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding" is not existing and "available" in some implementations but the real used algorithm is "AES/GCM/NoPadding" (see [Can PKCS5Padding be in AES/GCM mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248777/can-pkcs5padding-be-in-aes-gcm-mode) for more details).

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GcmTestBouncyCastle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
        System.out.println("Encryption & Decryption with BouncyCastle AES-GCM-Mode");
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792534/out-of-memory-exception-when-decrypt-large-file-using-cipher");
        // you need bouncy castle, get version 1.65 here:
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.65
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // setup files
        // filenames
        String filenamePlain = "plain.dat";
        String filenameEncrypt = "encrypt.dat";
        String filenameDecrypt = "decrypt.dat";
        // generate a testfile of 1024 byte | 1 gb
        //createFileWithDefinedLength(filenamePlain, 1024);
        createFileWithDefinedLength(filenamePlain, 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 1 gb
        // time measurement
        long startMilli = 0;
        long encryptionMilli = 0;
        long decryptionMilli = 0;
        // generate nonce/iv
        int GCM_NONCE_LENGTH = 12; // for a nonce of 96 bit length
        int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;
        int GCM_KEY_LENGTH = 32; // 32 = 256 bit keylength, 16 = 128 bit keylength
        SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] nonce = new byte[GCM_NONCE_LENGTH];
        r.nextBytes(nonce);
        // key should be generated as random byte[]
        byte[] key = new byte[GCM_KEY_LENGTH];
        r.nextBytes(key);
        // encrypt file
        startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        encryptWithGcmBc(filenamePlain, filenameEncrypt, key, nonce, GCM_TAG_LENGTH);
        encryptionMilli = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMilli;
        startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        decryptWithGcmBc(filenameEncrypt, filenameDecrypt, key, nonce, GCM_TAG_LENGTH);
        decryptionMilli = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMilli;
        // check that plain and decrypted files are equal
        System.out.println("SHA256-file compare " + filenamePlain + " | " + filenameDecrypt + " : "
                + Arrays.equals(sha256File(filenamePlain), sha256File(filenameDecrypt)));
        System.out.println("Milliseconds for Encryption: " + encryptionMilli + " | Decryption: " + decryptionMilli);
        // clean up with files
        Files.deleteIfExists(new File(filenamePlain).toPath());
        Files.deleteIfExists(new File(filenameEncrypt).toPath());
        Files.deleteIfExists(new File(filenameDecrypt).toPath());
    }

    public static void encryptWithGcmBc(String filenamePlain, String filenameEnc, byte[] key, byte[] nonce, int gcm_tag_length)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(gcm_tag_length * 8, nonce);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmSpec);

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filenamePlain);
             BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filenameEnc);
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out)) {
            //byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[0x10000]; // = 65536
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    bos.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                bos.write(obuf);
        }
    }

    public static void decryptWithGcmBc(String filenameEnc, String filenameDec, byte[] key, byte[] nonce, int gcm_tag_length)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filenameEnc);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filenameDec)) {
            //byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[0x10000]; // = 65536
            int len;
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(gcm_tag_length * 8, nonce);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmSpec);
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    out.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                out.write(obuf);
        }
    }

    // just for creating a large file within seconds
    private static void createFileWithDefinedLength(String filenameString, long sizeLong) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filenameString, "rw");
        try {
            raf.setLength(sizeLong);
        } finally {
            raf.close();
        }
    }

    // just for file comparing
    public static byte[] sha256File(String filenameString) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int count;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filenameString));
        while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            md.update(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        bis.close();
        return md.digest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kai, good to hear that this solution is working for you. Could you kindly mark this as accepted answer? Thx.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be an issue with the implementation of the GCM mode. I'm not sure that you can work-around it.

If you look at your stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decrypt(GaloisCounterMode.java:505)
```

The out-of-memory error is happening when writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` from within `GaloisCounterMode`. You use a `FileOutputStream`, so either you're not showing the right code or this `ByteArrayStream` is used internally.

If you look at the [source for GaloisCounterMode](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/GaloisCounterMode.java) you'll see that it defines an internal `ByteArrayOutputStream` (it actually defines two, but I think this is the one that's the problem):

```
    // buffer for storing input in decryption, not used for encryption
    private ByteArrayOutputStream ibuffer = null;
```

Then, later down, it writes bytes to this stream. Note the code comment.

```
    int decrypt(byte[] in, int inOfs, int len, byte[] out, int outOfs) {
        processAAD();

        if (len > 0) {
            // store internally until decryptFinal is called because
            // spec mentioned that only return recovered data after tag
            // is successfully verified
            ibuffer.write(in, inOfs, len);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

That buffer isn't reset until `decryptFinal()`.

---

**Edit**: looking at [this CSx answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/plain-text-size-limits-for-aes-gcm-mode-at-2gb-with-sun-jce-implementation) it looks like GCM needs to buffer the entire stream. That would make it a very bad choice if you have large files and not enough memory.

I think your best solution is to switch to CBC mode.

Comment: You have ["buried the lead"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bury_the_lead). Your edit should be at the top of the answer.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - I would prefer that the OP be able to understand their exception, rather than jump immediately to an answer.